# RxJs - transform array of Observables to an array of emitted values

Tags: rxjs

Sorry for the title, I couldn't think of a better one.
I've got this piece of code, which basically:

1. filter for valid (non-null) cron epressions' arrays
2. map each cron expression to a call to a service

---

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
    op.filter(v => !!v.cronExpressions),
    op.map((v): string[] => v.cronExpressions),
    op.map((v: string[]) => v.map(cron =>
            this.cronService.getReadableForm(cron).pipe(
                op.map(this.toDescription),
                op.map((description): CronExpressionModel => ({ cron, description }))
            )
        )
    ),
    // What now?
).subscribe((cronExpressions: CronExpressionModel[]) => ...) // Expected result
```

I'd like to get, on `subscribe()`, the array of `CronExpressionModel` returned from all the services calls.

I can't wrap my head around this.

---

Current solution, as per Martin answer:

```
filter(v => !!v.cronExpressions),
map(v => v.cronExpressions),
map(cronExprs => cronExprs.map(c => this.invokeCronService(c))),
mergeMap(serviceCalls => forkJoin(serviceCalls).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transform a stream into an array, you can use [toArray](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/toarray.html) operator.

Here's a suggestion:

```js
this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
    filter(v => !!v.cronExpressions),
    // transform [item1, item2...] into a stream ----item1----item2----> 
    concatMap((v): Observable<string> => from(v.cronExpressions).pipe(
        // for each of the items, make a request and wait for it to respond
        concatMap((cron: string) => this.cronService.getReadableForm(cron)),
        map(this.toDescription),
        map((description): CronExpressionModel => ({ cron, description })),
        // wait for observables to complete. When all the requests are made, 
        // return an array containing all responses
        toArray()
      )
    ).subscribe((cronExpressions: CronExpressions[]) => ...) // Expected result
```

**Note :**

You can use `mergeMap` instead of `concatMap` to parallelize the requests. But you need to know what you're doing ;)

Comment: Uhh, that's starting to become complicated hahaha.
Could you clarify why you're transforming the string array to an Observable array with the first ConcatMap?

Comment: if you use `...map( (sArray: string[ ]) => sArray.map( v=> anObservable))` you'll get something like : `[Obs1, Obs2, Obs3...]` as output. You don't want to create N streams, I guess. With this implementation, you will have to use a forkJoin, or subscribe to each element of your array of observables. 
I think that it's more elegant to rely on one single stream. ----RawItem1---RawItem2--- > that you transform into ---RaffinedItem1---RaffinedItem2--- etc. and wait for the stream to end.
The idea of using the first concatMap is to always keep one single stream.

Comment: Ok, give me a couple minutes the process what you just wrote

Comment: So, I was trying out your solution, but apparently toArray is never called, because valueChanges never complete

Comment: @LppEdd I didn't know that your original Observable doesn't complete. I just updated my answer, I think now it's working.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah it works now. I suppose it is because the `from` stream now completes correctly. I've edited my answer to show the code using martin solution. The only think I find a bit "off" is the use of `map` to transform the string to an Observable

Comment: Yes, `toArray` is a special "accumulate and concatenate" operator that waits for the stream to end. The idea is similar in `bufferTime` or `bufferCount` that concatenate the results within a time or after N values. 
Explanation of my `concatMap` : you have N requests to make; for each request, you need to make a call (generate an observable). You can either create N observables and concatenate them (`forkJoin` does this), or create one single stream and emit N times inside it. I choose the second option.

Comment: Ok! Do you feel the stream way is the better for a functional-reactive approach?

Comment: under the hood, martin solution and mine are equivalent in terms of results. But the logic is different. With `forkJoin`, you start with an array of observables. So you have to build those before. With `concatMap/mergeMap`, you start with an array of values, and you get to define how to transform the values into observables. 
I find the second approach more convenient, as it's more condensed. While the first approach is a bit more verbose, it offers more flexibility.
But I guess what I'm saying is biased. It's more like team "Array of Observables is ok" vs "no, it isn't", so...debatable ! :)

Comment: Well I think you explained it very well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `forkJoin` if you don't mind running all requests in parallel:

```
switchMap(observables => forkJoin(...observables))
```

Or if you want to run all of them in sequence:

```
switchMap(observables => concat(...observables).pipe(toArray()))
```

Instead of `switchMap` you might want to use `concatMap` or `mergeMap` depending on what behavior you want.