# RxJS toArray not being called

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got an RxJS sequence as follow:
(control is an Angular `FormControl`)

```
control.valueChanges.pipe(
    concatMap(cronExprs => from(cronExprs as Array<string>)),
    concatMap(cron => this.invokeCronService(cron)),
    toArray()
).subscribe(cronExprs => this.setCronExpressionModels(cronExprs))
```

Say the cronExprs array has three items `['..', '..', '..']`. I can see, while debugging, the `concatMap(cron => this.invokeCronService(cron))` clojure is called three times, but `toArray` is never called, and obviously the subscribe clojure is never called too. Seems the sequence does not complete correctly.

`invokeCronService` is:

```
private readonly invokeCronService =
    (cron: string): Observable<CronExpressionModel> =>
        this.cronService.describeCron(cron).pipe(
            map(result => result.get()),
            map((description): CronExpressionModel => ({ cron, description }))
        )
```

`describeCron` is a simple:

```
public describeCron(cronExpression: string): Observable<Result<string>> {
    return of(Result.valid('', cronExpression))
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `toArray` operator will emit its buffer only after its source Observable completes.

In your case your source is `control.valueChanges` that never completes so `toArray` will never emit anything. It depends on what you want to achieve but you could use `scan()` to collect all emissions while remitting all intermediate results or use `take(1)` as the first operator that will ensure the chain completes after the first emission from `valueChanges`.

Comment: it's strange Martin, it worked 'till yesterday. If you remember you answered my question a couple of days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782041/rxjx-transform-array-of-observables-to-an-array-of-emitted-values

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm not using the `FormGroup` `valuesChanges`, but the `FormControl` one

Comment: In my example I used `toArray` on `concat(...observables).pipe(toArray())` where each Observable is so service call.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm actually using madjaoue solution. And it worked pretty good. That's what's strange

Comment: Solved using your way.